# check if url is relative to website

Tags: python, regex, pandas, http, url

I have big DataFrame of urls from various websites. I would like to check which website it is relative to. Characteristic to define website is its root url cleaned from extra info (for example, for `http://www.agpu.net/` root url will be `agpu.net`

So the main goal is to find to which root given url relates. For example, `http://www.mordgpi.ru/` should get tag `mordgpi.ru` but not `gpi.ru`. Also this should work not for root webpage url only, for example, `https://www.mordgpi.ru/our-life/news/46/55116/`

Dataset for urls look like:

```
url
---------------------
http://pnu.edu.ru/ru/
https://www.dvfu.ru/
http://donstu.ru/
http://www.elsu.ru/
http://ivgpu.com/
http://ivanovo.ac.ru/
http://www.isuct.ru/
```

And for roots:

```
root
-------------
pnu.edu.ru/ru
dvfu.ru
donstu.ru
elsu.ru
ivgpu.com
ivanovo.ac.ru
isuct.ru
```

For given url I tried to get root following way, but this doesn't work well:

```
root = roots['root'].str.lower().apply(lambda x: x in url).to_frame()
root = root[root.root]
```

Can I achieve this with regexp or somehow else? Appreciate any help

Comment: it seems like this site pnu.edu.ru/ru, has a different structure than remaining ones, as it's got extra '/ru' at the end  so it would follow a separate convention?

Comment: @Turo I suppose for `_root_` there should be some rule like `http(s)://(www.)_root_(/)(_smth_else_)` -> `_root_`

Comment: I just want to notice that what you call root has a different structure in the first example vs. remaining 6 ones. So these would be 2 different regex approaches.

Comment: Well for TLDs like `ac.ru` there is no rule to distinguish first part from a domain name using text-processing tools only if you have a list of allowed TLDs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `urlparse` in python 2.7 or `urllib.urlparse` in python 3+ for this:

```
from urllib import parse
split = parse.urlsplit(url)
netloc = split.netloc
path = split.path
if netloc.startswith('www.'):
    netloc = netloc[4:]
print(netloc + path.rstrip('/'))
```

Passes all your test cases.

The reason I used `urllib` is because regex may be ugly when you have long querystrings and advanced url formatting(including ports, etc). I let `urllib` take care of it so that you can easily fetch the `netloc` and `path`.